# Create a WP_Query where if the first value of the first row is equal to the second compare other value

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, meta-query

I want to create a query of a custom post type where the order is by a custom field and I want if the custom fields are equal to compare a second custom field.

```
$args = array (
    'post_type' => array( 'sn_dr_ia' ),
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key'  => 'thePrice',
);
```

These are my arguments and the result is ordering by `thePrice` field correctly and I want if `thePrice` field are equal to compare it with `thePrice2`

Comment: You want to _sort_ the results by the value of the meta field `thePrice` and in the second comparison by meta field `thePrice2`, correct?

Comment: @David Yes, i want the sorting to be by the thePrice meta field and if the two metas are equal the compare it with thePrice2 meta field

Comment: I have trouble following this. Do you want posts that have `thePrice` and `thePrice2`, equal to value? What the point of two different fields equal to each other?

Comment: @Rarst I need a query where the order is by thePrice, the price is meta field that takes values from 0-10. Lets say its olympic medals. I want to order all the countries that they have the most gold medals, and if three countries has the same gold medals i want to be ordered by the silver medals. Now u get me?

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup multiple meta_queries using an array. Since you didn't have a value you were looking for I'm just making sure that thePrice and thePrice2 are not blank. I set each meta query to a variable and then used them in the main orderby statement with a space between them. I wasn't able to do any testing on the code so if you have issues let me know.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'sn_dr_ia',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        'thePriceValue' => array(
            'key'     => 'thePrice',
            'value'   => '',
            'compare' => '!='
        ),
        'thePrice2Value' => array(
            'key' => 'thePrice2',
            'value'   => '',
            'compare' => '!='
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => 'thePriceValue thePrice2Value',
    'order'   => 'ASC'
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
?>
```

Here is a link to the codex for the syntax of the meta_query: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query